# How can I get Less map value by variable?

Tags: css, less

Why this doesn't work?

```
@colors: {
  red: #2A3F50;
}

.yyy{
  @color: red;
  color: @colors[ @color ];
}
```

Is in Less method to use variables with maps?
The error:

> Variable @color not found

PS:
but this code works fine:

```
@colors: {
  red: #2A3F50;
}

.yyy{
  @color: red;
  color: @colors[ red ];
  background-color: @color;
}
```

If I put `@@color` in [ ], it throws    `Variable @red not found`

Comment: @color: red;.yyy{
  color: @colors[ @color];
  background-color: @color;
}

Comment: see PS to ssilas777 above in post, please.

Comment: *If I put `@@color` in `[ ]`, it throws "Variable `@red` not found"* - because `red` in `@colors {...}` is not a variable but *property*. You'll point to it with `$@` not `@@`. I.e. in your case the code you want is `@colors[$@color]`

Comment: `@colors[@color];` will just look for a variable named `@color` in `@colors` (and it's not there).

Comment: seven-phases-max: thank you great sir! I've spent half a day trying different combinations. I'm amazed that you know this! I didn't find this on lesscss.org.